# What will happen if you use a armature on a merging mesh?

Tags: modeling, armature

If my mecha mesh arm's don't work on my model using armature because I merged to cylinder and a cube and some of the mesh are not merged there separated parts. Is it possible to animate a merged mesh and adding a armature on a merged mesh?

Comment: you can merge meshes and use the existing armature to move the new vertices, but maybe show some pictures so that we understand the situation better

Comment: It really depends on your whole mesh, I don't know how it looks without more information, all you will need to check is if weight painting is as it is supposed to be on your merged mesh